# Application Request Routing (ARR) with HTTP Methods and Mule

Tags: redirect, iis, mule, arr, http-method

I'm trying to **redirect messages** internet URL with the `Application Request Routing (ARR)`, the component to the `IIS` in **Windows Server**.

I want to redirect that messages by the HTTP Method. Example:

```
HTTP POST: http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:7050/api/createUser
HTTP DELETE: http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:7050/api/deleteUser
HTTP PUT: http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:7050/api/modifyUser
```

The **endpoint** will be Mule (**REST API Service with RAML**).

Is it possible to make this filter?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do it by using choice router with this MEL expression #[message.inboundProperties.'http.method'] ?